# Lightbox effect with pure JavaScript is not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement Lighbox effect on click of a Image using below code

```
        document.addEventListener('click',function(){
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
        if(target.className == "acv"){
            var id = target.id, src= target.src, 
            type = target.nodeName, imgW, imgH,
            temp = document.createElement('div'),
            sHeight = screen.availHeight,    
            sWidth = screen.availWidth,
            st = temp.style;
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function(){
                imgW = this.width;
                imgH = this.height;
            }
            img.src = src;
            var imgH = ( sHeight >= imgH + 20 ? imgH : (sHeight - 20) );
            var imgW =  ( sWidth >= imgW + 20 ? imgW : (sWidth - 20) );
            img.style.height = imgH;
            img.style.width = imgW;
            img.style.position = "relative";
            img.style.left = ( (sWidth - imgW) / 2 ) + "px";
            img.style.top = ( (sHeight - imgH) / 2 ) + "px";
            temp.appendChild(img);
            temp.id = "lightbox";
            st.width = sWidth + "px";
            st.height = sHeight + "px";
            st.backgroundColor = "Gray";
            st.zIndex = 123;
            st.position = "absolute";
            st.top = st.left = 0;
            st.margin = "0 auto";
            document.body.appendChild(temp);
        }
    });​
```

Please check the working fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9xMHn/7/).

And I feel like I have done something wrong in this. Please correct and help me to improve the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, if image already loaded onload event not fires, also it is mistake to try to use ImgW and ImgH initialised in event body  to use outside of scope of event handler, at least, you shold also "fix" img in event handler, so far here the code which work fine for the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/9xMHn/11/):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    if (target.className == "acv") {
        //     debugger;
        var id = target.id,
            src = target.src,
            type = target.nodeName,
            imgW, imgH, temp = document.createElement('div'),
            sHeight = screen.availHeight,
            sWidth = screen.availWidth,
            st = temp.style;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = src + '?rand=' + Math.random();
        //HIDE before we sure that image loaded!
        img.style.display = "none";
        var pos_img = function(img) {
            var imgH = img.height,
                imgW = img.width;
            imgH = (sHeight >= imgH + 20 ? imgH : (sHeight - 20));
            imgW = (sWidth >= imgW + 20 ? imgW : (sWidth - 20));
            img.style.height = imgH;
            img.style.width = imgW;
            img.style.position = "relative";
            img.style.left = ((sWidth - imgW) / 2) + "px";
            img.style.top = ((sHeight - imgH) / 2) + "px";
            //SHOW IMAGE BACK
            img.style.display = "block";
        };
        //image not loaded?
        if (img.complete === false) {
            img.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
                console.log("LOAD", e, img);
                //TODO remove EventListener ?
                pos_img(img);
            });
        } else {

            pos_img(img);
        }
        temp.appendChild(img);
        temp.id = "lightbox";
        st.width = sWidth + "px";
        st.height = sHeight + "px";
        st.backgroundColor = "Gray";
        st.zIndex = 123;
        st.position = "absolute";
        st.top = st.left = 0;
        st.margin = "0 auto";
        document.body.appendChild(temp);

    }
});​
```

also i would to use *window* width/height for calculate positions.

> please note that the code above not give you production code, it is just to show where is logic mistake. 
>  you may be not ask the question if try to click on jslint button

Comment: To complement that... I think one case where the image is already loaded and the `onload()` event is not fired occurs when is taken from the cache in some browsers.

Comment: yes you right, but it still need to fix onload handler (because image may be not loaded), i not make this in my sample, because after explanation i think OP will make it himself, and again - even if onload fires, the original code will not work, because it will probably fire after the `click` handler finished

Comment: that not conflicts - just no event. check `img.complete` attribute

Comment: Could you please update the code eicto. It would be very helpful for me.